# bash comparison with -lt returns true, but should be false

Tags: bash

I have a simple command to evaluate if there's enough free disk space on the root partition:

```
if [ $(df | awk '$6 == "/" {print $4}') -lt 30000 ]; then
        echo "Insufficient free disk space"
else
        echo "Disk space check OK"
fi
```

This returns "Disk space check OK" (ie, false), but the actual value returned from the df command is greater than 30000. So, I would expect the comparison to return true:

```
$ echo $(df | awk '$6 == "/" {print $4}')
38052168
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: `[ 38052168 -lt 30000 ]` is false.  So, the command, as written, is working correctly.    Did you want to use `-gt` in place of `-lt`?

Answer (score 1):

Mind the the `print "$4"` with awk prints the available disk space. If so
you may may use `sed` for this simple job but need to introduce some error checking as well, just in case, `df` returns an error.

I may try it like this

```
avail=$(df --output=avail / 2>/dev/null | sed 1d)
if [ -z "$avail" ] # $avail can be empty only df fails as per this case
then
echo "Error with df"
 elif [ "$avail" -lt 30000 ] # Your original logic is correct!!
then
 echo "Insufficient Disk Space"
else
 echo "Disk Check Passed"
fi
```

---

```
df --output=avail /
```

gives you output like  below

```
  Avail
8708124
```

Answer (score 0):

38052168 is not less than 30000 that is why the else block is running. instead of -lt use -gt or

```
if [[ ! com1 -lt com2 ]];then
    # do stuff
else
    # do stuff
fi
```